# SAS By-Group Processing: Assigning Values for Entire Group

Tags: sas, grouping

I have a huge data set containing individuals in which some have multiple ICD-9 code procedures. I need to create a few cohorts depending on which ICD-9 codes these individuals have, but my by-processing is not working how I intend it.

Here is a sample data set:

```
DATA TEST;
    INPUT ID: $5. CODE;
    FORMAT CODE Z4.;
    DATALINES;
    A   8006
    A   8155
    A   0080
    A   0081
    A   0082
    A   0083
    A   0084
    B   8006
    B   8155
    B   0080
    B   0081
    B   0082
    B   0083
    B   0084
    B   9999
    ;
RUN;
```

Subjects A and B have the exact same codes except that Subject B has an extra dummy code `9999`. Here, if the subject ONLY has codes 8006, 8155, and 0080 to 0084 (and nothing else!), then they are put into one cohort. Subject A should be one cohort, Subject B should be another due to the dummy code.

The code below doesn't do by-processing as I intend:

```
DATA TEST1; SET TEST;
    BY ID;
    IF CODE IN (8006,8155,0080:0084) THEN COHORT=1;
        ELSE COHORT=2;
RUN;

ID  CODE    COHORT
A   8006    1
A   8155    1
A   0080    1
A   0081    1
A   0082    1
A   0083    1
A   0084    1
B   8006    1
B   8155    1
B   0080    1
B   0081    1
B   0082    1
B   0083    1
B   0084    1
B   9999    2
```

I want it to look as such:

```
ID  CODE    COHORT
A   8006    1
A   8155    1
A   0080    1
A   0081    1
A   0082    1
A   0083    1
A   0084    1
B   8006    2
B   8155    2
B   0080    2
B   0081    2
B   0082    2
B   0083    2
B   0084    2
B   9999    2
```

It seems like it should be simple, but is there another way to use by-processing? I also tried putting the data into wide format, concatenating all the codes separated by comma and indexing, but this approach is cumbersome and not very dynamic. I appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the same person could have codes that would place them in multiple groups you need to define each group independently.  Create a separate variable for each cohort. You could use MAX() aggregate function in PROC SQL. But here is how I would do it using the DOW technique in a DATA step.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.id) ;
    set have ;
    by id;
    if code = '8154' then COHORT1=1;
    else if code in ('8006','8155') or '0080' <= code <= '0084' then COHORT2=1;
    else if code = '8151' then COHORT3=1;
    else if code = '8153' or '0070' <= code <='0073' then COHORT4=1;
    else if code = '8156' then COHORT5=1 ;
  end;
  if N(of COHORT1-COHORT5) > 1 then COHORT=6;
  else COHORT=whichn(1,of COHORT1-COHORT5);
  drop cohort1-cohort5 ;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tom. Does the `WHICHN` statement assign the `COHORT=0` values? I just want to be clear on the documentation.

Comment: Yes, the WHICHN() function will return 0 if the value is not found.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily in a proc sql step. The `case when` statements determine the cohort for each row like you did in your data step, and the `max` combined with `group by` finds the maximum value of the `case when` statements for each id. So if all rows for a given id have a `cohort_pre` value of 1, you get a max of 1; else you get a higher cohort.

```
proc sql;
    create table test1 as select distinct
        id, code,
        case when code = 8154 then 1
             when code in(8006,8155,0080:0084) then 2
             when code = 8151 then 3
             when code in(8153,0070:0073) then 4
             when code = 8156 then 5 else 99 end as cohort_pre,
            case when count(distinct calculated cohort_pre) = 1 then max(calculated cohort_pre)
            else 6 end as cohort
        from test
        group by id;
quit;
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the insight @superfluous. That works great for my example, but it looks like it could get messy given my actual cohort conditions:

`COHORT 1 = 8154
COHORT 2 = 8006,8155,0080:0084
COHORT 3 = 8151
COHORT 4 = 8153,0070:0073
COHORT 5 = 8156
COHORT 6 = any combination of 1-5`

Ha I see what it's doing, but I'm not too familiar with complex SQL statements so I could see where this would get pretty hairy. My test data probably didn't help my cause the way I described it.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you want cohort6 to work? I updated the code to show how the others would factor in.

Comment: Someone classified as Cohort 6 would have, for example, 8154 and 0073 which is a combination of Cohort 1 and Cohort 4. I think I could just add another `case when` line list all the values above in a similar fashion. This is great though, thank you for adding those additional lines.

Comment: It's a little trickier than that - you need to calculate the number of unique cohorts there are for each id, and if it's > 1, the cohort is 6; else it's the maximum value of cohort_pre (which should be 1 through 5 or 99 in this case if the value of code is not in those that you supplied).